# Strange behavior of rugarch package on cluster

Tags: r, amd-processor

I watch a very strange behavior of `rugarch` package when I try to estimate models via `arfimafit` method. I have some (usually 1-2) workers never stop after the method calling in parallel.

Code for reproduce:

```
library(aTSA);
library(parallel);
library(rugarch);
library(pracma);


maxThreads <- max(1, detectCores()-1);
internalCluster <- makeCluster(maxThreads, homogeneous=FALSE, XDR=FALSE);

libraries <- c('data.table',  'rugarch', 'arfima', 'portes');
clusterExport(internalCluster, c('libraries'));
clusterEvalQ(internalCluster, { invisible(lapply(libraries, require, character.only=TRUE)); });

ARParam <- MAParam <- 0:3;
distribs <- c("norm", "snorm", "std", "sstd", "ged", "sged");
mean <- c(TRUE, FALSE);

arfimaNeed <- TRUE;
dFrac <- 0.1;

grid <- expand.grid(ARParam, MAParam, distribs, mean);  
names(grid) <- c("AR", "MA", "DISTRIB", "MEAN");
permutationVec <- randperm(c(1:nrow(grid)), nrow(grid));

permGrid <- grid[permutationVec, ];

seriesGlobal <- parLapply(internalCluster, 1:1000, function(i) { as.numeric(arfima.sim(100, model = list(phi = c(0.2, 0.1), theta = c(0.5), dfrac = .2, dint = 0))); });


for (i in 1:1000)
{
  cat('\n Iteration ', i, ' started \n');
  
  ##series <- rnorm(100);   
  series <- seriesGlobal[[i]];
  
  tmpEnv <- new.env(hash = FALSE);
  assign('arfimaNeed', arfimaNeed, envir = tmpEnv);
  assign('series', series, envir = tmpEnv);
  assign('dFrac', dFrac, envir = tmpEnv);
  assign('permGrid', permGrid, envir = tmpEnv);
  
  clusterExport(internalCluster , c('permGrid', 'arfimaNeed', 'dFrac', 'series'), envir = tmpEnv);
  
  specs <- parLapply(internalCluster, 1:nrow(permGrid), function(i) { arfimaspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(permGrid[i, "AR"], permGrid[i, "MA"]), include.mean = permGrid[i, "MEAN"], 
                                                                                                   arfima = arfimaNeed), 
                                                                                 distribution.model = as.character(permGrid[i, "DISTRIB"]), 
                                                                                 fixed.pars = list(arfima = dFrac)); });
  models <- parLapply(internalCluster, specs, function(elem) 
  {
      try(arfimafit(spec = elem, data = series, solver = "gosolnp"), silent = TRUE);
  });
  
  cat('\n Iteration ', i, ' finished \n');
}

stopCluster(internalCluster);
rm(internalCluster);
gc(T, T);
```

and execution result:

[image]

[image]

My system:

- AMD Ryzen 5950X,
- 128 Gb RAM,
- AMD64 Family 25 Model 33 Stepping 2 AuthenticAMD ~3401 Mhz
- BIOS Version: American Megatrends Inc. 4408, 28.10.2022
- OS Windows 11 OS Version 10.0.22621 N/A Build 22621
- R 4.2.2, R 4.2.2 Patched, R 4.3 Devel were tested.
- gcc 12.2.0

(I use RTools 4.3 now)

All packages were built with `-m64 -O3 -w -march=native -mfpmath=both -mfma -mtune=native` options.

I also use AMD BLIS + LibFlame libraries in ST mode (I copy and rename these libraries from AOCL installation folder and named it as Rblas.dll and Rlapack.dll for AMD BLIS and AMD LibFlame dlls).
But the same behavior of this code was observed also on `OpenBLAS` build with `-fno-fma` key.

It's really strange and stupid problem for me. I have my other code written earlier worked fine on my previous Intel Skylake-6770K with MKL.

Did anyone get the same problem with `rugarch` package?

Thank you.

P.S. I found that current problem exists only with solvers based on Rsolnp package - `solnp`, `gosolnp` (`nloptr` solver code usage was commented in sources by alexios). `nlminb` and `lbfgs` work fine. I really do not know the reason - I tried to install `Rsolnp` and `truncnorm` from binaries with no effect.